# Changing STARTS for mplusModeler in R

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to up the number of starting values in Mplus when I pass objects through the program using the mplusModeler package in R, specifically the mplusObject function. Is there a way to specify the number of starts (e.g., 100 10) instead of the defaults? Or is this something I can only do in Mplus and there's no way to do this from R?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

You add the command to the ANALYSIS section of the input. For example:

```
  lpa_model <- mplusObject(
    TITLE = "3-Class LPA;",
    VARIABLE = "USEVARIABLES = x01-x15;
    CLASSES=c(3);",
    ANALYSIS = "ESTIMATOR = MLR;
    TYPE = MIXTURE;
    STARTS=100 10;",
    MODEL = " [code continues...]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).